# Convert SQL join statement to JPQL

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpql

I have 3 tables with the following structure.

### User

uid
username
password

### Friend

id
uid
fid

### Post

pid
uid
msg

I want to find all the posts that the friends of a user did. In SQL I extract that using this statement:

```
SELECT post.* FROM Post 
INNER JOIN Friend f ON f.fid = post.uid 
INNER JOIN User u ON f.uid = u.uid
WHERE u.uid = 1;
```

How can I convert this to JPQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JPQL queries entities and their associations, and you haven't described them, so it's a bit hard to say. But assuming a Post has a ManyToOne with a Friend, and a Friend has a ManyToMany with a User, the query would be:

```
select post from Post post
inner join post.friend friend
inner join friend.users user
where user.uid = 1
```